# How do I change the selected icon background color for a Material3 BottomNavigationMenu?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, material-design

I'm currently working on my first Android application for university. I've used a BottomNavigationMenu as my main source of navigation through the app, with the Material3 theme. However, I can't figure out how to change the purple highlight that you can see below.

[Screenshot here - wouldn't let me embed it as I'm on a new account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKjDJ.jpg)

I've tried Googling it but I can't seem to find any answers relevant to Material 3.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.